# Woocommerce only show subcategories on main category page

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, filtering

I have a webshop with categories and subcategories. Ofcourse my webshop contains products.

**The problem:**

When I go to a category: A list of sub categories is displayed AND products are displayed.

**What I want:**

I only want to display subcategories on the category page, without the products.

The products only need to be displayed on the deepest category page.

**Example:**

This is how it looks right now:

-Category #1

--- product associated to SUBcategorie #1.

--Subcategory #1

---- product associated to subcategorie #1.

And this is how I want it :

-Category #1

--Subcategory #1

---- product associated to subcategorie #1.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own category template.

The file should be [taxonomy-product_cat.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/taxonomy-product_cat.php)
Also look at the [archive-product.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/archive-product.php)

Your custom code should go around the `woocommerce_product_loop_start`
Also check the [woocommerce codex](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/)

This should get you stared.